# Ribbon across container in Bootstrap 3 not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, containers, ribbon

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm trying to apply a ribbon across a container using the example on this site:
http://www.andreapinchi.it/css3-ribbon-effect/

I've created a mock-up of the problem here:
http://jsbin.com/rebexatijizi/1/edit

Doesn't look much like the other. :(

*NOTE: JSBIN link updated above to show current status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/tibaqenawena/4/edit

CSS:

```
.ribbon, .ribbon:before, .ribbon:after {box-sizing:content-box;}
```

[image]

You can also just adjust the math in your css to include padding and borders. DEMO: http://jsbin.com/dupac/1/edit

```
div.both_ribbon::before{
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -2px;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid rgb(0, 80, 116);
}

div.both_ribbon::after{
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -2px;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid rgb(0, 80, 116);
  }
```

Also, your css is messed up and it still is, you have a enclosed a style within another style.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you didn't select this as the answer.

Comment: It's very close. It fixes the problem with ribbon ends not appearing correctly. I guess I'm still not quite there. The background of the body should be the #f5f5f5, and the page/container that has the ribbon wrapped on it should be white with the shadow as in the example. I'm still trying to get it though.

Comment: ahh. Well I'm going to dinner now, be back tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks. The  {box-sizing:content-box;} piece is some help for sure. I just don't understand the rest. Still trying.

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding: `padding-left: 0px;  padding-right: 0px;` to the container

Answer (score 0):

Your box-sizing properties seem to be messing everything up.  In bootstrap.css remove the box-sizing rules.  Also, take the padding off of your container (you can add another child element within your container that has padding instead).  Here is the code you should remove:

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

:before, :after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Oh... I'm hoping not to delete anything from BS3 standard css files if that's possible (you're saying to remove the above from bootstrap.min.css?)

Comment: You're right though -- commenting the above from bootstrap.min.css does "fix" the ribbon issue, but it breaks sizing of many other things for me unfortunately.

Comment: This should still work if you add this code in your custom CSS file, sorry for the late response.  If it still does not work, you can make your CSS selectors more specific by prefixing the code above with a container ID.